# Concatenate string in formula in a special case

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I'd like to concatenate in a formula, like this in my VBA code:

```
  .Formula = "=INDIRECT(" ""'testsheet'!G"" & 4*i ) " //i = 3 for example
```

Because I'd like to see that:

```
='test_sheet'!G12
```

But it's not working. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some quotes are wrong here. The following code worked for me:

```
.Formula = "=INDIRECT('testsheet'!G" & 4*i & ")"
```